# Online Index Rebuild shows self blocking

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, online-operations

I've been doing some testing on rebuilding some larger clustered indexes (with online + sort_in_tempdb on) and I'm observing something that I can't immediately explain.  I have a hunch that this is some sort of intra-query blocking due to the rebuild going parallel but can't 100% confirm.  Running SQL 2016 EE - SP2 + CU8 (13.0.5426)

**The query I'm running:**

```
USE [UserDB]
GO
ALTER INDEX [PK_Order] ON [dbo].[Order] REBUILD WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, ONLINE = ON)
GO
```

**Whoisactive says:**

[image: whoisactive output]

**Digging further into that session and it's ecids, I see the following:**

[image: ecid info]

Now, with sort in tempdb (dbid 2) being on, my concern here is that the `resource_description` column is showing page locks on dbid5 (the DB that I'm rebuilding the index on).

This looks like a page lock on the user database that may cause blocking or disruptions.  Can anyone shine some light on what exactly is happening here? Is this just unbalanced parallelism and threads have to sit on their hands until the others finish?

Worth noting that these locks do clear after a while (5-10 mins) and we revert back to just CXCONSUMER waits.

Comment: If you don't specify `MAXDOP` in the command, it will inherit the `max degree of parallelism` instance level config value ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).  I only mention this because there's a pretty good chance these statements are *always* executing as parallel execution plans unless you've got `max degree of parallelism` set to `1`.

Comment: Also, I don't think specifying `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` changes the fact that the command takes a shared modification lock (`SCH-M`) which can definitely cause locking [under the certain scenarios](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/01/testing-alter-index-rebuild-wait_at_low_priority-sql-server-2014/) which I find tends to happen more frequently on larger databases.

Comment: Would that occur on a test box with no traffic though?  Literally, nothing else on the box except me.

Comment: I suspect your blocking is self-blocking at this stage, and sadly, `sp_WhoIsActive` doesn't do the best job of identifying the proper waits in those scenarios.  I'd say run your test again and try out Paul Randal's [WaitingTasks.sql](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/updated-sys-dm_os_waiting_tasks-script/) query while things are self-blocking as this will show a better breakdown of what's going on under the covers.

Comment: That's what I used to generate that screenshot at the end.  That's self blocking right?  That was my theory initially so I'm looking for confirmation that makes sense.